# Ruby access derived class "class methods" from base class

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I have a base class in Ruby that has a class method which it has inherited. I would like to call this method in the base class, but pass it an option which is specified by the derived class, like so:

```
class Base < SuperDuperClass
  super_duper_class_method :option => my_option_value

  def self.my_option_value
    raise "Method my_option_value must be overridden by all subclasses"
  end
end

class Derived < Base
  def self.my_option_value
    "My Derived Option Value"
  end
end
```

However, this isn't working. I believe it's because the top-level code in the base class is executed before the top-level code in the derived class, so the derived method is not defined when super_duper_class_method is called. I'd rather not have to call super_duper_class_method in all the derived classes, but just specify the option instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off, my solution is to call `super_duper_class_method` in the subclasses. This is what I was trying to avoid, but in this situation, I don't think it's possible to get what I was going for without some pretty wild metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't specific when you said it wasn't working.  I believe you will get an exception raised when the Base class is defined, (rather than when my_option_value is called).

I suggest that you pass the method name as a symbol, and in the SuperDuperClass, call send on self to call the derived method.

```
class SuperDuperMethod
  def self.some_code
    self.class.__send__(options[:option])
  end
...
```

Comment: You can also call __send__ instead of send.

Comment: I should have mentioned: the SuperDuperClass is from a library, so it would be best if I didn't have to monkey-patch it to get this to work. When I use `self.send` in the base class instead of calling the method directly, I get a NoMethodError

Comment: It's not monkey patching.  Send does the same thing as calling a method.  My bad was that since you are calling a class method, you need to send on the class.  I'll edit my answer.